# Applying a function to multiple arrays/matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, function

Given two arrays:

```
a = array(1:3)
b = array(3:1)
```

I want to apply a function that sequentially compares the value of each element of A to each element of B, and return the result.

Something like:

```
compare = function(xa, xb) { if (xa < xb) { 1 } else { 0 } }
```

...where xa would be the an element from the a array, and xb would be an element from the b array.

Is there a derivative of apply I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: After looking at questions posting requirements for CV, its possible this should be moved to Stack Overflow. Anyone with the reputation to do so feel free if its more appropriate there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than `mapply` I would use R internal recycling rules for vectorised functions. If `a` and `b` are the same length you need only do this:

```
as.integer( a < b )
#[1] 1 0 0
```

`as.integer` is just there to coerce to `1` or `0`, in reality `TRUE` and `FALSE` will behave as `1` and `0` in any subsequent multiplicative operations.

#### example

```
set.seed(1); a <- sample(10)
#[1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1

set.seed(2); b <- sample(10)
#[1]  2  7  5 10  6  8  1  3  4  9

a < b
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

a * ( a < b )
#[1] 0 4 0 7 2 0 0 0 0 1

a[ a < b ]
#[1] 4 7 2 1
```

Some people may be surprised, but `<` is a function. It calls an underlying `C` function called `do_relop` in the files `/src/main/relop.c` (all the logical comparators do - they just use a different switch for the type of comparison) which handles vector recycling. You can write `<` like this:

```
`<`( a , b )
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

#### Benchmarking

Using the primitive `<` operator is over 100 times quicker (on a pair of 1e6 length vectors) than using `ifelse` which is also a vectorized function:

```
set.seed(1); a <- sample(10,1e6,repl=T)
set.seed(2); b <- sample(10,1e6,repl=T)
require( microbenchmark)
bm <- microbenchmark( comparealt(a,b) , `<`(a,b) , times = 25L )
print( bm , digits = 3 , unit = "relative" , order = "median" )
#Unit: relative
#             expr min  lq median  uq  max neval
#            a < b   1   1      1   1  1.0    25
# comparealt(a, b) 131 126    122 105 48.3    25
```

Comment: Wouldn't you expect 100 TRUE or FALSE results if you compare "the value of each element of A to each element of B"?

Comment: @Henry I think you are misinterpreting the question. Look at the output in the answer provided by the OP. I believe they are referring to an element-wise comparison, not an outer product. I think `x` in their pseudo-function is an indexing vector.

Comment: I don't see an example in the original question, but now I see juwiley gave an answer too, so you are probably correct.

Comment: @Henry *where xa would be the an element from the a array, and xb would be an element from the b array.* I take `x` to be the same element from both arrays, hence element-wise.

Comment: Excellent answer, unfortunately I was probably unclear in my use case.  I need to pass variables to the function, and use for comparison, so a simple a < b wont work.  Yes I was meaning element wise.  Thanks for taking the time

Comment: @juwiley you *can do that*! Look further down my question: `\`<\`( a , b )` essentially `a < b` can be anything and `<` is a function that takes two arguments so you can programmatically pass *anything* to to it. It will be 100 times quicker than `ifelse`.

Comment: Alright, you win. ;)  Mind blown, the R learning curve is feeling steep

Comment: @juwiley its easy to do stuff, I guess harder to do stuff well. I still get lots of things very wrong and I have been using R a long time!

Answer (score 1):

I originally read "the value of each element of A to each element of B" meaning an outer join and suggested:

```
compare <- function(x, y){ outer(x, y, FUN="<")+0 }
```

which for example gives

```
> compare(array(1:6), array(5:3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0
[6,]    0    0    0
```

For comparing matrices of the same dimension elementwise you could use something like

```
comparemat <- function(mat1, mat2){ (mat1 < mat2)+0 }
```

or

```
comparealt <- function(mat1, mat2){ ifelse(mat1 < mat2, 1, 0) }
```

where either of

```
comparemat(matrix(1:12,nrow=4), matrix(12:1,nrow=4)) 
comparealt(matrix(1:12,nrow=4), matrix(12:1,nrow=4))
```

give

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0
```

Comment: Why would you define `comparealt <- function(mat1, mat2){ ifelse(mat1 < mat2, 1, 0) }` to use `ifelse` when you could just do `matrix(1:12,nrow=4) < matrix(12:1,nrow=4)`?!

Comment: It is a function because that is what the question asked for.  `comparemat` gives the simple comparison you ask for, while `comparealt` uses `ìfelse` to illustrate a vectorised if, which seems to be more than 8 times faster for large cases than mapplying `ìf` in juwiley's `gg`answer (though 8 times slower than `comparemat`)

Comment: `<` *is* a function. See the edit in my question for the slightly more surprising way of expressing this function. `a < b` is convenience notation, but `<` calls a `C` function called `do_relop` with the `LTOP` switch to do logical comparison for `<`. Don't reinvent the wheel to make it worse! I'm just trying to help you. If you really wanted you could do `flt <- function( a , b ) a < b` but this would be equally silly! `<` works element-wise on matrices as well.

Comment: @SimonO101 `<` gives a boolean result but the question asks for a number so you need to convert. One way to do it is to add 0, which preserves any matrix structure, and that is what `comparemat` does.

Comment: Ok, I'm giving up. Last try: `TRUE == 1 ; FALSE == 0` I suggest trying that.

Comment: This is essentially what I needed.  Thanks to you both

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon 'mapply', which seems to do the trick:

```
> gg = function(x,y){ if(x < y) { 1 } else { 0 }}
> gg(1,2)
[1] 1
> gg(2,1)
[1] 0
> mapply(gg, 1:4, 4:1)
[1] 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: I don't intend to be rude, but this is very inefficient R code. Both in performance and readability.

Comment: Any suggestions as to why this is inefficient and unreadable?  I'm new at R, so would appreciate feedback if this is obvious.

Comment: The function `<` can compare *vectors* `x` and `y` of any given size in a single call. Using `mapply`, you make R reinterpret the expression for every pair of elements . So you get not only a faster code but a more compact expression using something like `as.integer(x<y)` or even `ifelse(x<y, 1, 0)`.